# Airflow timetable randomly skips runs

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-taskflow

I have built a timetable that is designed to run during specific times of the day, using the provided time range. Here is the time range object that I use for the timetable.

```
class TimeRange:
def __init__(self, start_time: Time, end_time: Time, tz: Timezone = timezone("UTC")):
    self.start_time = start_time
    self.end_time = end_time
    self.tz = tz
    self._validate()

def _validate(self):
    if self.start_time > self.end_time:
        raise AssertionError("End time shouldn't be earlier than the start time")

def is_within(self, check_time: Time):
    return self.start_time <= check_time <= self.end_time

def duration(self) -> timedelta:
    return self.end_time - self.start_time

def __str__(self) -> str:
    return f'{self.start_time} - {self.end_time}, {self.tz._name}'
```

Here is my timetable, which inherits some functionality from both DeltaDataIntervalTimetable and CronDataIntervalTimetable. The issue is that it randomly skips task runs.

```
class TimeRestrictedDDITimetable(DeltaDataIntervalTimetable, CronDataIntervalTimetable):
""" Airflow timetable that schedules between specific times and using a custom interval.
    It can exclude specific dates.
"""

def __init__(self, time_range: TimeRange, delta: timedelta, excluded_dates: Optional[DateSequence] = None) -> None:

    self._time_range = time_range
    self.excluded_dates = excluded_dates

    num_intervals, remainder = divmod((self._time_range.end_time - self._time_range.start_time).in_seconds(), delta.total_seconds())
    self._end_interval = self._time_range.start_time + Duration(seconds=int(num_intervals * delta.total_seconds()))

    DeltaDataIntervalTimetable.__init__(self, delta)
    DeltaDataIntervalTimetable.validate(self)

@property
def summary(self):
    summary = f'{self._time_range}, interval: {self._delta}'
    return summary

def infer_manual_data_interval(self, run_after: DateTime) -> DataInterval:
    return DataInterval.exact(run_after)

def _get_next(self, current: DateTime) -> DateTime:

    # current is always in UTC timezone
    current = current.in_tz(self._time_range.tz).naive()

    if (current + self._delta).date() > current.date():
        # next delta changes the date so we start with the next date and the start time
        next_run = DateTime.combine((current + self._delta).date(), self._time_range.start_time)

    elif (current + self._delta).time() > self._end_interval and current.time() < self._end_interval:
        # next delta goes out of bound of end interval but current time is inside the end interval
        # next run is fixed to be on the end interval
        next_run = DateTime.combine(current.date(), self._end_interval)

    elif current.time() >= self._end_interval:
        # current time is out of bound of end interval so we start the next day with the start time
        next_run = DateTime.combine(current.date() + timedelta(days=1), self._time_range.start_time)

    elif (current + self._delta).time() < self._time_range.start_time:
        # next delta is out of bound of start time so we start the same day with the start time
        next_run = DateTime.combine(current.date(), self._time_range.start_time)
    else:
        # current + self._delta is between start_time and _end_interval of the same day as current
        # so we need to iterate to understand which interval it falls into
        next_run = DateTime.combine(current.date(), self._time_range.start_time)
        while next_run <= current:
            next_run += self._delta

    # if excluded dates are defined and next_run date is in excluded dates
    # get the next available date with the start time of the time range
    if self.excluded_dates and next_run.at(0, 0, 0).set(tz='UTC') in self.excluded_dates.dates:
        while next_run.at(0, 0, 0).set(tz='UTC') in self.excluded_dates.dates:
            next_run += timedelta(days=1)
        next_run = DateTime.combine(next_run.date(), self._time_range.start_time)

    # make next_run timezone aware
    next_run = next_run.set(tz=self._time_range.tz)

    return next_run

def _get_prev(self, current: DateTime) -> DateTime:

    # current is always in UTC timezone
    current = current.in_tz(self._time_range.tz).naive()

    if (current - self._delta).date() < current.date():
        # prev delta changes the date so we start with the previous date and the end interval
        prev_run = DateTime.combine((current - self._delta).date(), self._end_interval)

    elif (current - self._delta).time() < self._time_range.start_time and current.time() > self._time_range.start_time:
        # previous delta goes out of bound of start time but current time is inside the range
        # previous run is fixed to be on the start_time
        prev_run = DateTime.combine(current.date(), self._time_range.start_time)

    elif current.time() <= self._time_range.start_time:
        # current time is out of bound of the range so we start the previous day with the end interval
        prev_run = DateTime.combine(current.date() - timedelta(days=1), self._end_interval)

    elif (current - self._delta).time() > self._end_interval:
        # previous delta is out of bound of end interval so we start the same day with the end interval
        prev_run = DateTime.combine(current.date(), self._end_interval)
    else:
        # current - self._delta is between start_time and _end_interval of the same day as current
        # so we need to iterate to understand which interval it falls into
        prev_run = DateTime.combine(current.date(), self._end_interval)
        while prev_run >= current:
            prev_run -= self._delta

    # if excluded dates are defined and next_run date is in excluded dates
    # get the next available date with the start time of the time range
    if self.excluded_dates and prev_run.at(0, 0, 0).set(tz='UTC') in self.excluded_dates.dates:
        while prev_run.at(0, 0, 0).set(tz='UTC') in self.excluded_dates.dates:
            prev_run -= timedelta(days=1)
        prev_run = DateTime.combine(prev_run.date(), self._end_interval)

    # make prev_run timezone aware
    prev_run = prev_run.set(tz=self._time_range.tz)

    return prev_run

def _align_to_next(self, current: DateTime) -> DateTime:
    return CronDataIntervalTimetable._align_to_next(self, current)

def _align_to_prev(self, current: DateTime) -> DateTime:
    return CronDataIntervalTimetable._align_to_prev(self, current)

def _skip_to_latest(self, earliest: Optional[DateTime]) -> DateTime:
    return DeltaDataIntervalTimetable._skip_to_latest(self, earliest)

def serialize(self) -> dict[str, Any]:
    self._delta: timedelta
    return {
        "delta": self._delta.total_seconds(),
        "start_time": self._time_range.start_time.for_json(),
        "end_time": self._time_range.end_time.for_json(),
        "timezone": self._time_range.tz._name
    }

@classmethod
def deserialize(cls, data: dict[str, Any]) -> Timetable:
    delta = data["delta"]
    start_time = Time.fromisoformat(data["start_time"])
    end_time = Time.fromisoformat(data["end_time"])
    timezone = data["timezone"]
    return cls(TimeRange(start_time=start_time, end_time=end_time, tz=Timezone(timezone)), timedelta(seconds=delta))
```

This is my simple DAG that I execute with an empty operator. It is set to run every 2 minutes from 16:00 to 20:00. While this specific example could be achieved using cron, I need to configure it for intervals not aligned to whole hours. For instance, I want it to run every 10 minutes from 16:20 to 20:40.

```
import pendulum
from pendulum.tz.timezone import Timezone
from datetime import timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator

from my_airflow_plugin.timetables import TimeRestrictedDDITimetable, TimeRange

timezone = Timezone("Europe/London")

with DAG(dag_id='delta_custom_timetable_dag',
         description='Delta Custom Timetable DAG',
         start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 8, 8, tz=timezone),
         timetable=TimeRestrictedDDITimetable(
             time_range=TimeRange(
                 start_time=pendulum.time(16, 0, 0),
                 end_time=pendulum.time(20, 0, 0),
                 tz=timezone
             ),
             delta=timedelta(minutes=2),
         ),
         catchup=False
         ) as dag:

    task = EmptyOperator(task_id='empty_task')
```

Here, you can observe that it skips runs randomly, sometimes even several in a row.
[image]